# How can I find out if a hash has an odd number of elements in assignment?

Tags: perl, hash

How could I find out if this hash has an odd number of elements?

```
my %hash = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
```

Ok, I should have written more information.

```
sub routine {
    my ( $first, $hash_ref ) = @_;
    if ( $hash_ref refers to a hash with odd numbers of elements ) {
        "Second argument refers to a hash with odd numbers of elements.\nFalling back to default values";
        $hash_ref = { option1 => 'office', option2 => 34, option3 => 'fast'  };
    }
    ...
    ...
}


routine( [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ], { option1 =>, option2 => undef, option3 => 'fast' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is: You get a warning about it:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at...
```

Assuming you have not been foolish and turned warnings off.

The hard answer is, once assignment to the hash has been done (and warning issued), it is not odd anymore. So you can't.

```
my %hash = (1,2,3,4,5);
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;

$VAR1 = {
      '1' => 2,
      '3' => 4,
      '5' => undef
    };
```

As you can see, `undef` has been inserted in the empty spot. Now, you can check for undefined values and **pretend** that any existing undefined values constitutes an odd number of elements in the hash. However, should an undefined value be a valid value in your hash, you're in trouble.

```
perl -lwe '
    sub isodd { my $count = @_ = grep defined, @_; return ($count % 2) }; 
    %a=(a=>1,2); 
    print isodd(%a);'
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at -e line 1.
1
```

In this one-liner, the function `isodd` counts the defined arguments and returns whether the amount of arguments is odd or not. But as you can see, it still gives the warning.

Comment: Good explanation. I like the 4 line one-liner. :)

Comment: @sid_com Well, no, you can still count the arguments before assigning them to the hash. And then deal with it in some suitable way.

Comment: @simbabque The linebreaks are purely for visual effect. =P

Answer (score 7):

Well, I suppose there is some terminological confusion in the question that should be clarified.

A hash in Perl *always* has the same number of keys and values - because it's fundamentally an engine to store some values by their keys. I mean, key-value pair should be considered as a single element here. )

But I guess that's not what was asked really. ) I suppose the OP tried to build a hash from a list (not an array - the difference is subtle, but it's still there), and got the warning.

So the point is to check the number of elements in the *list* which will be assigned to a hash. It can be done as simple as ...

```
my @list = ( ... there goes a list ... ); 
print @list % 2; # 1 if the list had an odd number of elements, 0 otherwise
```

Notice that `%` operator imposes the scalar context on the list variable: it's simple and elegant. )

**UPDATE** as I see, the problem is slightly different. Ok, let's talk about the example given, simplifying it a bit.

```
my $anhash = { 
   option1 =>, 
   option2 => undef, 
   option3 => 'fast'
};
```

See, `=>` is just a syntax sugar; this assignment could be easily rewritten as...

```
my $anhash = { 
   'option1', , 'option2', undef, 'option3', 'fast'
};
```

The point is that missing value after the first comma and `undef` *are not the same*, as lists (any lists) are flattened automatically in Perl. `undef` can be a normal element of any list, but empty space will be just ignored.

Take note the warning you care about (if `use warnings` is set) will be *raised* before your procedure is called, if it's called with an invalid hash wrapped in reference. So whoever caused this should deal with it by himself, looking at his own code: fail early, they say. )

You want to use named arguments, but set some default values for missing ones? Use this technique:

```
sub test_sub {
  my ($args_ref) = @_;
  my $default_args_ref = {
    option1 => 'xxx',
    option2 => 'yyy',
  };
  $args_ref = { %$default_args_ref, %$args_ref,  };
}
```

Then your test_sub might be called like this...

```
test_sub { option1 => 'zzz' };
```

... or even ...

```
test_sub {};
```

Comment: I suppose this doesn't work in my case where the list is passed as hash reference?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `__WARN__` signal to "trap" for when a hash assignment is incorrect.

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $odd_hash_length = 0 ;   
{
  local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $msg = shift ;
    if ($msg =~ m{Odd number of elements in hash assignment at}) {
      $odd_hash_length = 1 ;
    }
  } ;

  my %hash = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) ;
}

# Now do what you want based on $odd_hash_length
if ($odd_hash_length) {
  die "the hash had an odd hash length assignment...aborting\n" ;
} else {
  print "the hash was initialized correctly\n";
}
```

See also [How to capture and save warnings in Perl](http://szabgab.com/how-to-capture-and-save-warnings-in-perl.html).

Comment: At such a solution, I was thinking too, but it seems to me too shaky.